# My app is not installed in real device

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have made an application (API 23) which work fine in emulator but when I try to installed in real mobile, shows the message "**Apps not installed**" Please reply my query based on the following points:

1. The API was set 23 and mobile is having API 23.
2. I have not signed as you can see in below pic as I don't know how to sign:

[image]

So please help me out by giving me the solution.

App is transferred to the phone which is about 0.5 MB. but it shows the message "Apps not installed" My question is how to install this app file in mobile which is transferred from C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\SimpleApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debut.apk file to mobile. I don't want to upload the app on googleplay. Any how want to give the app to my friend Circle.

Comment: Build a **Signed APK** and try again

Comment: install apk by Android Studio USB Cable, by Run. or Generate Signed Apk.

Comment: Have you turned on developer mode on the phone ?
Link to check out how to if you have not
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html

Comment: . App is transferred to the phone which is about 0.5 MB. but it shows the message "Apps not installed" My question is how to install this app file in mobile which is transferred from C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\SimpleApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debut.apk file to mobile. I don't want to upload the app on googleplay. Any how want to give the app to my friend Circle.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually sign your APK.

In Android Studio click `Build` and then `Generate Signed APK`

Check the developer documentation under "Manually sign an APK" from the link
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html